# Using pandas.cut to split continuous variable, but it's skipping values?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use pandas.cut to categorise some continuous data - "capital gains".

Wondering if someone could please advise why some of the capital gains data points are not being binned accordingly?   For example the 159 counts of '99999', are not falling into the [45000, 110000] bracket.

I'm using the adult data set from this location.  https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/adult

```
df = pd.read_csv(...)
df['capital-gain'] = df['capital-gain'].replace(pd.cut(df['capital-gain'], [0,45000,110000,150000], right=False, include_lowest=True))
df['capital-gain'].value_counts()
```

the output is

```
[0, 45000)         32387
99999                159  #why is this here, and not falling into the group below?
[45000, 110000)        8
34095                  5
41310                  2
Name: capital-gain, dtype: int64
```

I have checked that data points do not have spaces in the field.

Thank you in advance to anyone who has time to respond.

Comment: What are you replacing values with? Could't you just use `df['capital-gain'] = pd.cut(df['capital-gain'], [0,45000,110000,150000], right=False, include_lowest=True)`?

Comment: This is a really interesting interaction in the way that the `categorical` dtype interacts with the values in the column via `replace`. Other than this really bizarre behaviour I agree with @yudhiesh you should not be using `replace` in addition to `pd.cut` and should assign the results of the categorical data back and call value_counts on that.

Comment: Thankyou, I thought I needed to tell python to update the data with the new values, i didn't realise that pd.cut also did that.

Comment: @HenryEcker yeah that behavior is really weird, if no argument is passed to `value` for `replace()` its set to `None` but still unsure why `99999` appears.

Comment: I can't replicate the issue, but I'm curious now. What version of `pandas` are you using @Amaranth? In 1.2.5 this produces the normal value counts as if replace was never called.

Comment: @henryEcker i'm using a jupyter notebook, which has pandas version1.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to replace the values instead just use the `pd.cut()` on its own.

```
df['capital-gain'] = pd.cut(df['capital-gain'], [0,45000,110000,150000], right=False, include_lowest=True)
```